# What is the word to express "to raise your both arms up and rotate them several rounds from back to front or the other way round"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

This is a very common warm-up exercise that most people do but I don't know how to say it.

You raise your both arms up and rotate them from back to front or the other way round as shown in the picture.

People say that is "**windmill**". Maybe, we can say "**he windmilled**".

What is the **general common phrase** to say it, for example, "**to spin/rotate your arms several rounds**" when you talk to a child?

Comment: Maybe you could google "large arm circles". There are lots of ways to move your arms that could be called spinning or rotating, so it will take more description than that to define the movement you are trying to describe.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, it seems like people say "do arm circles"

Comment: https://gfycat.com/speedypartialhypsilophodon and https://www.msn.com/en-ph/health/exercise/strength/arm-circles/ss-BBtOcCZ (The Internet still manages to surprise me, who knew there would be gifs?!)